# AS3 - What's the difference between MyClass(instance) and (instance as MyClass)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, casting

You can upcast or downcast an instance (to a superclass or subclass) using this syntax:

```
var i:MyClass = MyClass(instance);
```

But what does the `as` keyword do?

```
var i:MyClass = (instance as MyClass);
```

Are they equivalent? or am I missing something here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To put it in a few words:

- `as` is an operator. [The reference states](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#as): "If the first operand is a member of the data type, the result is the first operand. Otherwise, the result is the value null"
- the latter attempts a conversion. For primitives, this basically works, for complex values, this throws an exception unless the value is a member of the required type.

suppose, you have a class A and a class B.

```
var s:String = "4a";
trace(s as int);//null
trace(int(s));//4
var b:B = new B();
trace(b as A);//null
trace(A(b));//throws an error
```